# How to hide status bar on android studio app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I can't hide status bar on my android app

I've tried to use `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` and programmicaly `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` using java but nothing helped

Comment: Try looking at [Hide the status bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status).

Answer (score 0):

Set these properties in your theme:

- Hide the status bar

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`

- No action bar instead of title bar

`<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>`

- Remove the title bar

`<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`